# How cut some text from file in bash to specifiec symbol and write to another file?

Tags: bash

I have a text in the file look like below.

```
- $0 - The name of the Bash script.
- $# - How many arguments were passed to the Bash script.
- $@ - All the arguments supplied to the Bash script.
- $USER - The username of the user running the script.
- $SECONDS - The number of seconds since the script was started.
```

How I can cut all text which starts from "$" and end before "-" and save it to another file. How I can do it in bash script?

Comment: thx, but it's not worked for me. =(

Comment: All that I need is written in my question. After using your command I get this error. If I change "P" to"p" haven't any error but it's still not working. -
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

Comment: Thanks, now it's working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep you can use

```
grep -Po '\$.*?(?= -)' inputFile > outputFile
```

If you don't have GNU grep (for instance on Mac OS) you can use

```
perl -nle 'print $& if m{\$.*?(?= -)}' inputFile > outputFile
```